# Appending questions and answers into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am new to javascript and I have 2 strings
lets say

```
const questions = "1.What is love? 2.1+1 = ? 3. 2+2 = ?"
const answers = "1.Yes 2.2 3.4"
```

I want to append it into sth like :

```
const package = [{question1: answer1},{question2: answer2}]
```

I tried to split and append it through regex and split but it didn't work
Is there a way to individually append into a {} and then into the array of the package?

Comment: Have a look at `split()` and `map()` functions and to append it, you can have an array of objects

Comment: Just out of curiosity... **why** you use those two string format inputs to start with?? What if you create an answer that has the same format `N.` you're pretty much in problems regarding a proper parsing.

Comment: this is bad format. any number with dot in an answer or a question wll ruin it. choose another one or better use JSON

Comment: The answer to "What is love" can't possibly be "Yes.".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the result as:

```js
const questions = "1.What is love? 2.1+1 = ? 3. 2+2 = ?"
const answers = "1.Yes 2.2 3.4"

function splitArr(str) {
  return str.split(/\d+\./g).filter(Boolean).map(s => s.trim())
}

const ques = splitArr(questions);
const ans = splitArr(answers);

const result = ques.map((question, index) => ({ [question]: ans[index] }));
console.log(result);
```